# What DLL contains Windows 7 network icon?

Tags: windows-7, networking, icons

I am searcing for the location of the standard Ethernet-connected network icon in Windows 7, shown in this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGMCL.png]

I have checked these libraries:

```
- accessibilitycpl.dll
- compstui.dll
- DDORes.dll
- dmdskres.dll
- explorer.exe
- gameux.dll
- ieframe.dll
- imageres.dll
- mmcndmgr.dll
- mmres.dll
- moricons.dll
- netcenter.dll
- netshell.dll
- networkexplorer.dll
- pifmgr.dll
- pnidui.dll
- SensorsCpl.dll
- setupapi.dll
- shell32.dll
- wmploc.dll
- wpdshext.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, recheck `pnidui.dll`, this file contains many system network icons.

[image: your icon highlighted]

Also, [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/need-names-of-dll-files-that-contain-icons/2d3d9376-7576-4ce5-8b1f-f87461c219c1) you can find more info about system icons locations.

Comment: Damnit :| There it is. Looked past it because of the unfamiliar grey finish. Thanks. Great link too, that table posted is the most comprehensive list I've seen.